# Is it good to return a function call?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Assume there is a function called `foo`. We are going to write a function that calls foo at the end, like so (note that it's a real world scenario):

```
function update(string, callback) {
    if (arguments.count == 2) {
        if (typeof arguments[0] === 'string' && typeof arguments[1] === 'function') {
            updateRows(string, callback)
        } else {
            callback(Error('Invalid arguments.'))
        }
    } else if (arguments.count == 1) {
        if (typeof arguments[0] === 'function') {
            async.each(array, updateRows, callback)
        } else {
            callback(Error('Invalid arguments.'))
        }
    } else {
        callback(Error('Invalid arguments'))
    }
}
```

As you see, the error handler callback is written three times.

However, we could refactor the code using return statements:

```
function update(string, callback) {
    if (arguments.count == 2) {
        if (typeof arguments[0] === 'string' && typeof arguments[1] === 'function') {
            return updateRows(string, callback)
        }
    } else if (arguments.count == 1) {
        if (typeof arguments[0] === 'function') {
            return async.each(array, updateRows, callback)
        }
    }

    callback(Error('Invalid arguments'))
}
```

The code is now much cleaner than it was.

Hence, is it good to return functions from functions, is it a good practice? I scanned some code blocks written by Ryan Dahl, not had any consequence once.

Having not benchmarked the two, I don't believe there is a significant performance difference.

**EDIT:** As deceze warned me, we were not returning functions, we are just calling functions within return statements. Following that comment, I changed the question title to *'returning a function call'*. If it causes obfuscation, updates may be done based on suggestions.

Comment: You're not "returning functions", you're merely returning *from your function*. And you're returning the return value of the function you're calling.

Comment: @deceze I agree with you. Returned objects are not functions (they are undefined, though).

Comment: you're not returning functions from functions, you're return the result of various functions ... and if those functions return `undefined` there's no difference to what is returned by the `update` function

Comment: Your checks for one argument dont make sense, as `callback` will be undefined in that case.

Comment: if you're worried, change `return somefunc()` to `somefunc(); return;`

Comment: @robertklep I couldn't understand you, could you please give an example?

Comment: @Leviathlon if `arguments.length === 1`, it means only one argument was passed, which gets assigned to `string`. The `callback` argument would be undefined, but you're using it as callback for `async.each()`.

Comment: @robertklep Got it. Fixing it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure how much verbose needs to be your error message, if you really need to send error message by a wrong method usage, you can throw an error instead to return error in callback argument.

If you use a callback for anything, this callback should return data or errors about what was executed, if something wrong happens **before** callback, you have to send this information at your current execution and not wait for another one to give you this info.

And yes, you can return a function if you want.

So, here is a very simple suggestion with a hypothetical code:

```
function foo () {
  var isArgumentsValid = typeof arguments[0] == "string" && typeof arguments[1] == "function";

  if ( isArgumentsValid) {  
    return function () {
      // do your code here here
    }
  }

  throw Error()

  return null;
}

// usage

foo("bar", function(){console.log('after foo task')})()
```

Comment: I assume you meant function call, I'm already aware of I can return a function call. What I'm asking in the question is, is it encouraged by Javascript style guideliners and node community?

Comment: This is not a very common model in node, so if you want to follow node guidelines, don't return a function, you can return a boolean or something else, this model works great in for node or any js pattern.

Comment: Also, return a function is not wrong, in functional model is common and sometimes is a better option, for example, if you want to compose a execution or a command to be scheduled and executed later for other scope :)